# See error message from wp_insert_post function?

Tags: wp-insert-post, errors

I'm using `wp_insert_post` function to insert a new post:

```
$result = wp_insert_post(array("post_title"=>"test1"), true);
```

When I `echo` the result of the function, I get the number 335. How can I see what is the meaning of this code. I tried this with no success:

```
$error = new WP_Error($result);
echo ($error->get_error_message($result));
```

Comment: `var_dump($result);` or you can use `if( is_wp_error($result) ) echo $result->get_error_message();` (not tested) :)

Answer (score 5):

`335` is not an error message or code, it is the new post's ID that is retuned, so in short, the new post you have inserted was given the ID of `335`

### UPDATE

[`wp_insert_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) already returns a `WP_Error` object on failure, so simply `var_dump( $result );` would give you a specific error message on failure or the new post ID on success